# Are "Extensions" something that disappeared many Mac OS versions ago?

Tags: startup, login, safe-mode

On a sheet of Mac keyboard shortcuts for booting, one of them says, "hold down shift while booting and the computer will not load login items or extensions".

Am I wrong, or are Mac OS "extensions" something that were phased out a long time ago?  (In other words, with OS X Lion, the shift key simply cancels loading the login items, period?)

Note that, of course, I know that "extensions" has meaning in other apps -- Firefox, Safari, Thunderbird, etc.  But please confirm my Mac OS X suspicion as I describe it above.

(Yep, I know this is related to my other question.  Getting this answer clear will allow me to resolve both questions clearly and designate their correct answers.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your expectation that extensions are only a thing of the past is incorrect.

Modern Mac OS X uses kernel extensions, which are not identical to the "old school" extensions used in Mac OS 9 and earlier, but yes, there are still such a thing as extensions. You can find them in `/System/Library/Extensions`.

Apple expands on this in [this support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564) about Safe Mode.

Comment: To expand on the difference between Classic and OS X extensions: most, if not all, of the hardware drivers required by Classic Macs were included in the system software itself, *not* as separate extensions. In OS X most hardware drivers *are* provided as extensions.

Answer (score 0):

To go along with @Daniel's answer: holding down the shift key on startup of OS X should prevent "startup items" from opening.

Comment: You've said the same thing Daniel did. How is yours an "opposite answer"?

Comment: Woah!  I thought "kernel extensions" and "startup items" were different things!

Comment: I should say: your answers are *complimentary*, not identical. He explained extensions then vs. now, while you specified what the keyboard shortcut does. I've edited your answer to make that more apparent.

Comment: I read the document Daniel posted and it answered all the remaining questions I have! Sorry.  the above apple documnet at the bottom of daniel's answer is great. THANKS -- all done.

Comment: @estephan500 That's a great question, and it deserves to be asked as its own question, rather than trying to get an answer here in the comments thread.

Comment: thanks daniel -- in fact I deleted the question you are referring to in the thread -- got my answer in the document. thx!